# Do process repeatedly in the background?

Tags: android, ios, background, task

in the beginning I thought it would be fairly simple, but I guess it's not.
I want to call a URL every 10 minutes, either when the app is in the background or
in the foreground. How can I realize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `Service` with a `Handler` inside. Using directly `Thread`s is another approach but it's more likely it will be killed if the Android OS needs to free memory.

The `Handler` part would be something like this:

```
boolean stopHandler = false;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Do whatever you need
    ...

    if (!stopHandler) {
      handler.postDelayed(this, 600000);     // 10 minutes
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: okay so I can use this snipped and it will do something every 10 minutes? where do I need to embed it?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the `Handler` documentation, concretely at `postDelayed`. You need to put it inside a `Service`. You might want to have a look at this example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: thanks! will do. is there something similar for ios?

Comment: I have no idea, you should probably place a new question for iOS or change the question to address also iOS.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 7 you can schedule background operations for periodically fetching data from the network.  [This tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch--mobile-20520) is an example of scheduling background fetch operations -

Comment: and ios wont block it after a while?

Comment: Not if actually fetch data from the network - Apple won't look kindly on your app if you claim to be doing background fetch, but aren't.  Where people come unstuck is trying to use the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method - this only has limited time available - 10 minutes in iOS6 and 3 minutes in iOS 7